# How to restart the scrolling when using scrollable_positioned_list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) package for implementing an autoscroll feature. The autoscroll is working fine for the first time from 0th index to last index. But if the scrolling restarted from the 0th index, the scrolling is not working.

If we try to slide the listview the second time, it starts scrolling again.

The code that I have used is:

```
// Initialization
  final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
  final ItemPositionsListener itemPositionsListener =
      ItemPositionsListener.create();
```

```
// Positioned List Widget Usage
  Widget _detailedReportList() {
    return Expanded(
      child: ScrollablePositionedList.separated(
        itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
        itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
        // shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 60),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return _detailedReportListItem(
            context,
            index,
            _userErrorFramesUri(index),
            _trainerErrorFramesUri(index),
            _errorFramesText(index),
            _errorTimeInSeconds(index),
            _errorFrameIdx(index),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SizedBox(
            height: 2,
          );
        },
        itemCount: _detailedReportListCount(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
// Autoscrolling listview code
  if (itemScrollController.isAttached) {
     itemScrollController.scrollTo(
     index: errortimeList.indexOf(searchValue),
     duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
     curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic);
     if (!mounted) {
       return;
     }
     if (mounted) {
       // For changing the list item that is currently scrolled to
       setState(() {
         _selectedListIndex = errortimeList.indexOf(searchValue);
       });
     }
  }
```

Comment: because it scrolls when scrollcontroller is assigned to listview but when you scroll again its already assigned to listview.  but you can create a button or event on which you can call the method and start auto scroll.

Comment: can you give an example

Answer (score 0):

**create this method :**     and call this method on button click or any other event to start scrolling.

```
 void startScroll(){
        
          // Autoscrolling listview code
          if (itemScrollController.isAttached) {
             itemScrollController.scrollTo(
             index: errortimeList.indexOf(searchValue),
             duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
             curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic);
             if (!mounted) {
               return;
             }
             if (mounted) {
               // For changing the list item that is currently scrolled to
               setState(() {
                 _selectedListIndex = errortimeList.indexOf(searchValue);
               });
             }
          }
 
    }
```